Why do airplane air conditioning systems use a turbine to expand air?
Why do airplane air conditioning systems use a turbine to expand air?
The cooling medium in airplanes is air.
The Joule-Thomson effect causes the temperature to drop during expansion under these conditions. So why doesn't the air conditioning system rely on this effect as car air conditioning systems do with the R-134 refrigerant?
Is the pressure used in these systems too low for the temperature drop to be significant?
Expansion in the turbine is a process close to isentropic, and the additional work obtained during such expansion is necessary to lower the temperature?

This is arguably better suited for Aviation stack exchange. That being said, the main reasons I think are (1) bleed air compressed gas is widely available on aircraft powering many auxiliary systems and there is a weight advantage to using it as a common system; (2) freon (R-134) is highly flammable at elevated temperatures and pressures such as commonly found close to jet turbines; (3) aircraft operate with pressurized cabins continually heated by a variety of sources and the cooling power required is quite large.
